# Server backup to github

Tags: backup, git

Is it somehow possible to backup a whole server on github from the command line?

Something like:

```
cd /
git commit username/repos -patch master
```

I know it might not be this easy, cause it might need to turn the whole server into a git, and then also require a login for github and so on.

But is this possible to do? And would it be a good or bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it would work on github, who may have issues with large amounts of data stored on their servers (and hey, it may not even work). But client-side, you should have a look at git-annex:

> git-annex allows managing files with git, without checking the file
>   contents into git. While that may seem paradoxical, it is useful when
>   dealing with files larger than git can currently easily handle,
>   whether due to limitations in memory, time, or disk space.

https://git-annex.branchable.com/